# IIS URL rewrite rule using conditions

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have the following URL rewrite rule configured in my web.config file:

```
<rule name="Test Rule" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^(item=1|all|none|first).*$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/newsite/test.asp?{C:0}" />
</rule>
```

The following source url matches as expected.

```
http://domainname?item=1&param1=x%param2=y
```

However the rewritten url includes param1 and param2 in its query string. Shouldn't {C:0} only translate to what is matched in the regex group i.e. (item=1|all|none|first) and not anything that comes after it?

Comment: Try using `{C:1}` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the rewrite captures everything after the `( )` is because `{C:0}` grabs the entire match, and not just the group. Since you only want to capture what is within the `( )` (which is capture group 1) you would use:

```
{C:1}
```

Another example might be:

```
^(item=1|all|none|first)/(abc).*$
```

So to capture only `abc` for example (capture group 2):

```
{C:2}
```